# Libion.so no such file or directory while building firefox os

Tags: firefox

I want to install firefox os on samsung galaxy s2. For that i follow below steps.

```
$git clone git://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G.git
$cd B2G
$./config.sh galaxy-s2
```

and tried to built by typing the command

```
$./build.sh -j1
```

It gives me the following output

============================================

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP

PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.4.0.4.0.4

TARGET_PRODUCT=full_galaxys2

TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng

TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

TARGET_BUILD_APPS=

TARGET_ARCH=arm

TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon

HOST_ARCH=x86

HOST_OS=linux

HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-37-generic-i686-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty

HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER

OUT_DIR=out

============================================

Blob setup script has changed, re-running
Pulling files from ../../../backup-galaxys2
Pulling "libion.so"
cp: cannot stat ‘../../../backup-galaxys2/system/lib/libion.so’: No such file or directory
Failed to pull libion.so. Giving up.

Build failed!

Build with |./build.sh -j1| for better messages
If all else fails, use |rm -rf objdir-gecko| to clobber gecko and |rm -rf out| to clobber everything else.

My ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS, My target device is samsung galaxy s2, Model- GT-i9100, Android version-4.1.2. I follow the Firefox OS build prerequisites from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites

Could anybody tell me how can i solve this problem.